# How does firestore order documents

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have recently started a firestore database. I was wondering is there any order in which the documents are added? is it just in the order they are created in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no inherent sort order in which documents are stored, but you can specify the sort order you want to retrieve them in through the API. The documentation also contains a full table on [how data is sorted](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types).

If you're asking about the Firestore console, that by default orders the documents on their IDs, but you can change that by clicking the filter button at the top of the list of document IDs.

Comment: thank you for your reply! helps my understanding! one more question, when you say 'default order the document on their id' what do you mean?

Comment: The Firebase console shows the documents in the order of their document ID/name. Which typically is pretty random, so you'll definitely want to change the sort order if you are doing real work in the console.